# Embedding interactive Google Maps into a Google Form

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, geolocation, google-forms

I have a Google form with some questions. People can answer the questions about (future) trees they want to have in their neighbourhood. But there also must be the possibility that people mark the place of this tree on a (google) map in the same Google form.

So my question is: how can I add (embed) a Google Maps into a Google form so that people can mark a location and so that the latitude and longitude are included together with the other answers of the form?

I really want to have the possibility that people can mark this location on a map, because the address is not detailed enough and it also costs a lot of time otherwise afterwards.

I searched on the internet but can't find the answer!